# How to scroll down a page

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, appium

I want to scroll down to the bottom of the page, and perform an action. Using `uiautomator`, I have obtained the following:

```
index=2,
resource-id=com.manoramaonline.arogyam:id/pager,class=android.support.v4.view.ViewPager,
scrollable=true.
```

I have attempted to do this with the code below:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
RemoteWebElement element =(RemoteWebElement)driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.support.v4.view.ViewPager[@resource-id='com.manoramaonline.arogyam:id/pager']"));     
HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
scrollObject.put("direction", "down");

// This is where the error is
scrollObject.put("element", element.getId());
js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
```

Comment: Can you add some details about your automation like OS being used,automation app OS, appium version you are using etc

Comment: i am creating script for android app ,appium version is AppiumForWindows-1.2.4.1

Comment: I was able to scroll down using following code,                                  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.ScrollView"));
  HashMap<String, String> arguments = new HashMap<String, String>();arguments.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId()); ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("mobile: scrollTo", arguments); but got exception  info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":13,"value":{"message":"An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.","origValue":"Could not scroll element into view:

Comment: @PramodKumarG Did you get any solution for scrolling. I am also facing same issue

Comment: @testing, I got my issue solved as  i mentioned below in the answer

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by following code.

```
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.ScrollView"));
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(element);
    // actions.click();
    actions.perform();
```

Comment: I have tried with the code that you have mentioned above, but i am getting exception as   ** org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented.** , I am using Appium Java Client - 2.2 and Selenium verions 2.45. Could you please help me on this?

Comment: I have used selenium version 2.44 and java client 2.1.0. Try to run script in device.I got it working in device.

Answer (score 0):

```
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
            scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
            js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
```

This code will scroll downwards, you can specify how many times you wish for it to scroll by placing it into a for loop. Only downside is that it is a nonspecific code. Again, this code is from one of their github answers, and as I mentioned, Appium is incapable of doing any proper scrolls for iOS. At least, I haven't located anything.

Comment: Certainly a late response, however, seeing as mostly things involving driver.Scroll in Appium for iOS are utter garbage and are non functional. This code will scroll downwards, you can specify how many times you wish for it to scroll by placing it into a for loop. Only downside is that it is a nonspecific code. Again, this code is from one of their github answers, and as I mentioned, Appium is incapable of doing any proper scrolls for iOS. At least, I haven't located anything.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I will edit it later in the day, currently at work. But I do believe that the comment solves it as well.

Answer (score 0):

In recent update appium "mobile : scroll" deprecated, following code will work and video will help you to implement.

Scroll to text :

```
MobileElement radioGroup = (MobileElement) wd

.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()"

".resourceId(\"+<listview_id>+\")).scrollIntoView("

"new UiSelector().text(\"+<your_text>+\"));");

radioGroup.click();
```

This link will help you : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bT3tqaLNn-Y

Answer (score -1):

```
MobileElement radioGroup = (MobileElement) wd.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("
    new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceId(\"+<listview_id>+\"))
        .scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(\"+<your_text>+\"));
");
radioGroup.click();
```

method from [Manidroid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1312415/manidroid) works for me perfectly